# creating polygon object for geofencing ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby I want to write a Polygon object that will take an array of points in longitude and latitude (each point connecting to the next one in array order).  Now my main question is what is the best way to go about representing the edges (lines) between the two points so that I can then plugin a point and see if its inside or outside the polygon?

Is there a gem that easily adds this functionality?

This is all the code I have written so far

```
class Polygon
  attr_reader :vertices
  def initialize(vertices)
    @vertices = vertices
  end
end
```

Comment: I hope you are referring to convex polygons. If so, regular (equal sides) or not?. (I doubt that equal sides is much of a simplification.)

Comment: Yes I am referring to convex polygons

Comment: "so that I can then plugin a point and see if its inside or outside the polygon" has nothing to do with expressing the points of a polygon.

Comment: @sawa makes a good point. It sounds like what you really want is, given the vertices of a convex polygon, a method that would determine if a given point were inside the polygon. That would be more interesting as well.

Comment: yes, thats what I meant, sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Good. I suggest that you you do an edit to clarify. Don't change what you've written. Just add a clarification, something like: "**Edit:** Given a convex polygon in two-dimensional space, with vertices `v` (an array of 2-tuples), for any given point `x` (2-tuple) I would like a method `inside?(v,x)` which evaluates `true` if and only if the point `x` is inside or on the perimeter of the polygon.".  As no answers have been posted, I don't think there should be objection to such an clarification.

Comment: You have two votes to close. If you don't edit to clarify, there will be more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to determine if a given point is inside a convex polygon (or on an edge). (Note that the OP confirmed in a comment on the question that the polygons are convex.)

**Code**

```
def inside?(vertices, test_point)
  vs = vertices + [vertices.first]
  xi, yi = vertices.reduce([0,0]) { |(sx,sy),(x,y)| [sx+x, sy+y] }.map { |e|
    e.to_f/vertices.size } # interior point
  x, y = test_point
  vs.each_cons(2).all? do |(x0,y0),(x1,y1)|
    if x0 == x1 # vertical edge
      (xi > x0) ? (x >= x0) : (x <= x0)
    else
      k, slope = line_equation(x0,y0,x1,y1)
      (k + xi*slope > yi) ? (k + x*slope >= y) : (k + x*slope <= y)
    end
  end  
end
    
def line_equation(x0,y0,x1,y1)
  s = (y1-y0).to_f/(x1-x0)
  [y0-s*x0, s]
end
```

I have assumed the polygon is not a straight line (i.e., all vertices are not co-linear).

**Example**

```
vertices = [[5,1],[2,4], [2,8], [6,10], [9,6]]

inside?(vertices, [6,7]) #=> true
inside?(vertices, [9,9]) #=> false
inside?(vertices, [5,1]) #=> true
```

**Explanation**

Here's a graph of the polygon in the example.

[image]

Each edge of the polygon, if extended infinitely in both directions, forms a line that divides the plane into two parts. For a given point to be within the polygon (including points on edges), it must be on the sides of all of the lines formed by the edges that contain the polygon.

In the example, arrows indicate the applicable sides for lines going through `[5,1]` and `[2,4]`, and through `[2,4]` and `[2,8]`.  The equation for the line through `[5,1]` and `[2,4]` is found to be:

```
y = 6.0 - x
```

Points on either side of this line are therefore given by `6.0 - x <= y` and `6.0 - x >= y`.  To determine which inequality applies for each edge, we need an interior point of the polygon.  Since it's convex, many convex combinations of the vertices would do. If, for example, no three consecutive vertices were co-linear, we could use, say, the average of any two non-adjacent vertices.  I have chosen to use the point that is the average of all the vertices, which will be an interior point even if three or more (but not all) consecutive vertices are co-linear:

```
xi, yi = vertices.reduce([0,0]) { |(sx,sy),(x,y)| [sx+x, sy+y] }.map { |e|
           e.to_f/vertices.size }
  #=> [4.8, 5.8]
```

Returning now to the line that passes through the first two vertices, we see that:

```
6.0 - x = 6.0 - 4.8 = 1.2 => (1.2 < 5.8) => true
```

Hence, the interior point lies in the half-space given by:

```
6 - x <= y
```

We therefore apply the following test to see if the point of interest, `[6,7]`, lies within this half-space:

```
6.0 - 6.0 = 0 <= 7.0
```

It does, as does the point `[9,9]`.  If we were to consider the point `[2,2]`, we would find:

```
6.0 - 2.0 = 4.0 > 2.0
```

so would conclude the opposite, and return `false` from `inside?`.

Now consider the line passing through `[6,10]` and `[9,6]`, whose equation is:

```
y = 18.0 - 1.333*x
```

As

```
18.0 - 1.33*xi => 18.0 - 1.333*4.8 = 11.6 => (11.6 < 5.8) => false
```

The half-space associated with this line that contains the polygon is therefore given by the inequality:

```
18.0 - 1.333*x >= y
```

We can use this inequality to test if points fall within this half-space.  For `[6,7]`:

```
18.0 - 1.333*6 #=> (10.0 >= 7) #=> true
```

For `[9,9]`:

```
18.0 - 1.333*9 #=> (6.0 >= 7) #=> false
```

Comment: This won't work for all shapes. Imagine a T shape. Depending on the location in that T, an interior point can be on one side either to the left or right of both vertical lines, or between the two vertical lines. That is, if the shape isn't strictly convex, you have to try harder.

Comment: @briandfoy, you are correct. I edited my answer to make clear that both the OP and I are concerned with convex polygons. As to whether the polygons need be *strictly* convex (i.e., all interior angles are less than 180 degrees, as opposed to less than or equal to 180 degrees for convex polygons), I do not believe that is a requirement for my answer but you might want to look at that.

Answer (score 2):

The Accepted answer did not work for me, however after searching more I found this solution, which I converted into Ruby:

```
def inside?(vertices, test_point)
    sides = vertices.count - 1
    j = sides - 1
    point_status = false
    x, y = test_point
    vertices.each_with_index do |item_i, index|
        item_j = vertices[j]
        if item_i.y < y && item_j.y >= y || item_j.y < y && item_i.y >= y
            if item_i.x + (y - item_i.y) / (item_j.y - item_i.y) * (item_j.x - item_i.x) < x
                point_status = !point_status
            end
        end
        j = index
    end
    point_status
end
```

The original post is at:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62482/A-Simple-Geo-Fencing-Using-Polygon-Method

The Poster has also used another source which is:
http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Hope this helps someone.